# Const Static member function

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I saw everywhere that static member functions cannot be const. In the code below, I actually got output when I tried executing this with code blocks with static member functions being const. So, is this possible? Or only supported with newer versions of C++?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class s{
    public:static const int x=2;
    const static int fun(){
        return x+1;
    }
};


int main(){
    s obj;
    cout<<obj.x<<endl;
    cout<<obj.fun()<<endl;
    return 0;
}

output: 2
        3
```

Comment: The function is not constant. The int it returns is.

Comment: I have specified static function as const

Comment: If you whant a method to be `const`, the `const` goes at the end. If you put it at the beginning, it's the return value that is marked `const`

Comment: `const static int f()` is the same as `static const int f()`.

Answer (score 2):

`const` qualifier for member function must be written after function arguments list and it is not allowed for static member functions:

```
 static int fun() const // error const qualifier is not allowed on static member function
 {
```

You declared a function returning `const int` instead, though it does not make much sense either.